# Print issue after printing 1m x 2m rollup

Tags: print-design, pdf

I designed rollup 1m x 2m and sent PDF X-1a to printhouse but result is dissapointing.

Some text (curves) are oversimplified / weird.

I attached photo of design view in Adobe Acrobat (good) and printed version (bad).

Even my home printer printed it well (scaled).

Why it is happening? Whos fault is it?

Print:
[image: Print]

Design:
[image]

Print:
[image]

Design:
[image]

Comment: If you supplied art that looked correct, it's clearly the fault of the print provider.

Comment: Did the print house send you a graphic proof to review? I agree with above, this seems like the printer is at fault.

Comment: At the print shop they told me that they had printed digitally and there was no distortion, but they still think I had prepared the file badly for large-format printing. 
Only it's a PDF and the letters are shapes that don't look like that.
According to the printer the PDF should be flattened, but this requirement before printing was not in the description of how to prepare the file.
Even on my home printer it looks good.

Comment: Well.. if I send good art, as a PDF, *especially* with type outlined, to a print provider.. and they returned *those images* back to me.. it's their fault **entirely**. If the PDF needed flattening, they should have flattened it before printing. If the PDF was unacceptable for reproduction, they should have kicked it back to me before proceeding. At this point, all they are doing is *making excuses* and trying to get out of a refund or reprint... but it is 100% their fault if my PDFs looked correct. They may know all this.. and are just trying to see if you'll go away easily.

Comment: The **ONLY** way they should *not* provide a refund/reprint.. is if they asked you to approve a proof before proceeding, the proof showed the errors, but you approved it anyway. *Then*, the err lies with you - you shouldn't have approved a proof if it contained errors.

Comment: Just for the record.. I understand *why* you asked this here.. but it's not a great question for the StackExchange network since it's related to a *specific* project and really isn't so much about graphic design as it is just business operations. But again, I do grasp the need for some confirmation.

Comment: What software did you design this in. I mean powerpoint does this regularily for some reason.

Comment: @Scott Thank you for answear. I asked here beacuse tried to figure out what happened. If this is some kind of configuration of rpinter in printhouse or what. I did lots of different print designs and this happened first time. Weird because bigger fonts (also curves) are perfectly fine.

Comment: @joojaa Photoshop, cmyk with curves, export to PDF X-1a

Comment: heh.. PDFX-1a is a **flat file format**.. so, that  just blows up that excuse from them. Honestly, it's likely *nothing* you did and is entirely due to their process or equipment. There would appear to be *nothing* you could have done to prevent this on your end (which is why you are likely deserving of a reprint/refund).

Comment: Well, i dont think you are at fault  As such but it really looks like a precision problem of sorts. Really weird so it might be their RIP, the only other thing that i can think of is that the file was designed very out of scale and scaling is totaly out of bonkers. Just ask for them to reprint/refund you. They will make you whole, every good printshop will do this no questions asked.